# POCO is not an IDictionary or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, casting

I'm casting POCO objects to IDictionary/IEnumerable in a custom serializer I use. Its been in use for about a year with no failures. However I've got a class that simply does not cast as an IDictionary/IEnumerable. All the following return false:

```
(obj is IDictionary); // false
(obj is IList); // false
(obj is IEnumerable); // false
```

The class is defined as: (names changed, there are more properties)

```
internal class MyClass {
   public int ID;
   public string Text;
}
```

What gives? What cannot some objects be casted as IDictionaries? I need some way to enumarate through the properties as key/value stores, reflection not preferred.

Comment: Is your code example missing something? MyClass does not implement IDictionary.

Comment: The previous collections of objects that worked must have implemented IDictionary. If that were not the case, the cast would have failed. What kind of collection are the objects in? What is the output of your custom serializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyClass` does not implement `IDictionary`, hence it cannot be casted to `IDictionary`. Nor it implements `IEnumerable` and `IList`, so it won't cast to either of them, too.